# Is it possible to throw an Exception when accessing unloaded Navigation properties in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Recently I turned off LazyLoading in my application, because I hoped it made me more aware of the amount of sql queries I was sending. Problem is that when I forget somewhere to load an Entity before trying to acces it, it just returns null (instead of an Exception). This means my logic wrongly assumes the value is null, causing all kind of problems later in the flow.

I know there is the IsLoaded flag, but first of all you have to add boilerplate code, and second of all this is still something you can forget to check.

Is it possible to let the Entity Framework automatically throw an Exception when accessing an unloaded navigation property? It seems the right way to me, why would you ever want to ignore the fact that your Entity isn't loaded and just let the program continue?

Or am I thinking in the wrong direction? :|

(Btw EntityCollections are even worse, because they simply return an empty list like nothing is wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not any automatic way to do that. Theoretically you can create custom T4 template to generate your entities and check `IsLoaded` in every property getter. If you want to use POCO approach this will not help you because such check will break POCO rules and make your entities dependent on EF. If you are using `EntityObject` based entities you can try such approach.

Comment: I'm using DB First, but it sounds like a lot of work. Would you recommend doing this?  How are you dealing with this problem yourself?

Comment: It should not be such a big deal. You will start with existing template and just update property getter generation code for navigation property.